# Using a snippet for "degrees Celsius" without a space (snippets inside a string)

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I decided to write a snippet for "degree Celsius" - so that I could easily type `°C` without having to fiddle with *Character Map*. I came up with this snippet:

```
'*':
  'degrees Celsius':
    'prefix': 'C'
    'body': '°C'
```

And the idea is that if I want to type `°C` I can type `C, Tab`, and it gets automatically replaced. However, I ran into a problem.

I like to type my degree symbols adjacent to the number, without leaving a space. But when I type `123C, Tab, .` the result is not `123°C.` but `123C    .` because the snippet engine apparently attempts to match the full `123C` instead of just `C` (which actually makes perfect sense in hindsight).

Is there any way around this behavior? I've found that I can type `123 C, Tab` and then quickly go back and delete the space, but this a bit clumsy and slows down my typing. Is there a way to have Atom match only part of the string?

---

*Note:* I know that the recommended practice is to leave a space between number and degree symbol for temperature. I would still like to know the answer to my question, because (a) I prefer to ignore the best practice in my personal writing and (b) I'd like to know it for the general case of inserting a snippet mid-string.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do there... I had a bit of a look through the source code for the snippets package, however it doesn't seems to support any wildcard or regex matching.  It would be relatively easy to build a package that would insert `°C` into the editor given a certain key sequence.  Have a look at the 'Modifying Text' example: http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/package-modifying-text/

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you, it isn't using snippets but your `init.coffee` and a key stroke to perform a RegEx replacement based upon the current position of the cursor.

### *Solution #1*: Map a keyboard shortcut to insert a character

1. Open your `init.coffee` by selecting `File` -> `Init Script...` and paste the following at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
     'custom:insert-centigrade': ->
       atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
         'custom:insert-foo': ->
           atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('foo')
   ```
2. Open your `keymap.cson` by selecting `File` -> `Keymap...` and paste the following at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
     'ctrl-shift-space': 'custom:insert-centigrade'
   ```
3. Reload atom by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
4. Now open a new editor window and enter the following text:

   ```
   127
   ```
5. While the cursor is still to the right of the `7` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> your text should now be replaced with:

   ```
   127°
   ```
6. You can then continue typing your `C` as you normally would.

### *Solution #2*: Map a keyboard shortcut to convert character codes

1. Open your `init.coffee` by selecting `File` -> `Init Script...` and paste the following at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
     'custom:replace-centigrade': ->
       if editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
         editor.selectWordsContainingCursors()
         for range in editor.getSelectedBufferRanges()
           text = editor.buffer.getTextInRange range
           replacement = text.replace /([0-9]+)C/, '$1°C'
           editor.buffer.setTextInRange range, replacement
   ```
2. Open your `keymap.cson` by selecting `File` -> `Keymap...` and paste the following at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
     'ctrl-shift-space': 'custom:replace-centigrade'
   ```
3. Reload atom by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
4. Now open a new editor window and enter the following text:

   ```
   127C
   ```
5. While the cursor is still to the right of the `c` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> your text should now be replaced with:

   ```
   127°C
   ```

I've also created a short animation in case my instructions are not quite clear enough:

[image: Animation of Init Script in situ]

Comment: Couldn't you just assign `Ctrl+Shift+Space` to print `°C` as a hotkey?

Comment: absolutely, I use this technique myself after your original question gave me the idea! However, I found that after a while the number of keyboard shortcuts to remember become cumbersome as I use numerous different characters (`“`, `”`, `÷`, `×`, `©`, `®`, `™`, `➡`, `✔`, `✓`, `✗`, `✘`, `☐`, `☑`, `☒`), which is why I started moving towards a RegEx based solution which I will probably eventually convert into a package in time.